# How to remove lines from File A that are in File B using Windows powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, windows-7

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816914/how-to-join-two-text-files-removing-duplicates-in-windows) is excellent for joining two files.  I need to do sort of the opposite.  I need to remove lines from File A that are in File B, using powershell.

*This* question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580073/delete-lines-from-file-a-that-is-in-file-b), except that question is for unix and this is for Windows 7 powershell.

The files are hosts files.  Each one has lines consisting of:

- `127.0.0.1   host.domain.com`

or

- `0.0.0.0   host.domain.com`

or

- `# this is a comment`

Files may have up to 200,000 lines.  Spaces and tabs may be present.

Although I prefer it to be preserved, order does not effect function.

Here are some examples of hosts files:

- https://adaway.org/hosts.txt
- https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts&showintro=0&mimetype=plaintext
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts
- https://hosts-file.net/ad_servers.txt
- http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt
- http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/hosts

(Don't worry about `0.0.0.0` vs `127.0.0.1` for this question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this snippet:

```
$in1And2 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```